# FFMPEG: mcompand filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the "mcompand" audio filter with FFMPEG :
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mcompand

But it looks like the filter does not exist and I don't understand why or how I can install it..

I'm running the following command :

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "mcompand=0 0:1 1:-90/-900 -70/-70 -30/-9 0/-3:6:0:0:0" out.wav`

Here is the output :

`ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'input.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : Pro Tools
    originator_reference: 8hQM2ATxHVjaaaGk
    date            : 2017-12-19
    creation_time   : 10:32:43
    time_reference  : 2724864
  Duration: 00:00:46.22, bitrate: 1066 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1058 kb/s
File 'out.wav' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x14260a0] No such filter: 'mcompand'
Error opening filters!`

Anyone know what I can do?
Thanks.

Comment: It was recently added. Get a git binary from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: @Mulvya still getting the same message. The FFMPEG version I tried is 3.4.2-static.

Comment: @Mulvya I was using the release binaries and not the git binaries. Using the git binaries seems to fix the 'No such filter: "mcompand"' error! Thanks!

Comment: @Mulvya You should add your comment as an answer so I can upvote it.